# Finding value of a radio in a form after checked? Javascript DOM

Tags: javascript, validation, dom, radio-button

I currently have this form, and I am trying to get the value of the radio buttons when it is checked but I continually keep on having an error, what may be the problem with the code below?

html

```
  <form name="radioset2" id="radioset2" action="survey.html">
    <fieldset>
     <span class = "question"> question1 </span>
       <div id = "radio1">
            <label for="r_q1_id">Yes</label>
            <input id="r_q1_id" type="radio" name="r_q1_name" value="yes" />
       </div>
       <div id = "radio2">
            <label for="r_q2_id">No</label>
            <input id="r_q2_id" type="radio" name="r_q1_name" value="no" />
       </div>                                       

      </fieldset>
  </form>
```

javascript

```
function validRadio() {
var radio_buttons = document.getElementsByName.elements['r_q1_name'];
for(var x=0; x<radio_buttons.length; x++) {
    if(radio_buttons[x].checked) {
    alert(radio_buttons[x].value + " button is checked");
    } else {
    alert(radio_buttons[x].value + " button is not checked");
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Watch the syntax highlighting closely...

Comment: `document.getElementsByName.elements`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName

Comment: close the quote, if its not a typo: `+ " button is checked");`

Comment: just fixed the typo, and closed the quote

Comment: "but I continually keep on having an error" - what does that mean?

Comment: the error just means that nothing happens, I have it so the when I press submit, it performs the function validRadio()

Comment: you should call your function in the form action

Answer (score 0):

If you are targetting modern browsers, you can simply use the [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/%3achecked) CSS selector with the [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector) function to get the value of the checked input. That would remove the need of looping over the inputs.

http://jsfiddle.net/4uy2V/

```
var val = document.querySelector('[name=r_q1_name]:checked').value;
```

Comment: I tried using this method but, all of a sudden all of my javascript stopped working

Comment: @iplayjumanji2, wich browser are you using? Does the console gives you any errors?